# What's the problem with serial connection in the following code (running on Raspberry Pi 4, Raspbian OS)?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, serial-port

this serial connection thing on RPi should not be this challenging, though right now I'm facing something quite weird

**This is the code:**

```
   .
   .
   import serial
   .
   .
   ser=serial.Serial(
       port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
       baudrate=115200,
       parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
       stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
       bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
       timeout=1
   )
   .
   .
```

**The Error is:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 265, in open
    self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NOCTTY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/rtu-v4/dnp3/rtu.py", line 27, in <module>
    timeout=1
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 240, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 268, in open
    raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 2] could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'
```

**I alraedy checked out:**

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=224369

https://github.com/brendan-w/python-OBD/issues/137

**and ran the following commands in terminal:**
`sudo pip3 uninstall serial`
`sudo pip3 install pyserial`

**The Device is a Raspberry Pi 4**

Any Help would be appreciated.
Thnx.

Comment: you are trying to connect to device which does not exist. so what is your question? - look at dmesg when you insert your device to see what name udev gives your device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message "No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'" means that you do not have a device conected to you USB0.

You can use the command:

```
lsusb
```

to find out which ports are available and then change in you code de USB name to connect with the rigth device.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to communicate (I assume) with a USB to serial adapter, you can use **dmesg** to get the device that it is attached to the ttyUSB0.
In a terminal type this command:

```
dmesg|grep ttyUSB*
```

It will print out all the devices that are attached to all ttyUSBs.
In my case the result is:

```
[ 5072.316991] usb 3-1: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

If there were more devices connected, the result would have listed ttyUSB1/2..etc.

Should you disconnect the device, running the same command in a terminal will show the disconnection message:

```
dmesg|grep ttyUSB*
```

`[ 5361.353142] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0`